# What things a student should avoid?

Tags: guru, gurukul

How should a student lead his life specifically what should he avoid while gaining knowledge?

Comment: not sure abt Don't's but this shloka is famous for Do's.. "काक चेष्टा, बको ध्यानं, स्वान निद्रा तथैव च । अल्पहारी, गृहत्यागी, विद्यार्थी पंच लक्षणं ॥

Comment: Can you plz translate it.

Comment: "A student should be alert like a crow, have concentration like that of a Crane and sleep like that of a dog that wakes up even at slightest of the noise. The student should eat scantily to suffice his energy needs and neither less not more. Also he should stay away from chores of daily house hold stuff and emotional attachment." ~ [Source](https://hindi.theindianwire.com/%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%95-%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9F%E0%A4%BE-232988/)